# WordPress theme directory naming

Tags: themes, textdomain

Suppose, I named my WordPress Theme folder as TrueLove. Look 'True' is in the uppercase 'T' and 'Love' is in 'L'. This folder name is the slug of that theme that I found using this function echo get_template(). And I found it in an article that theme textdomain should match the slug. According to that article I have to register my textdomain as 'TrueLove'.

Is there any problem with this folder name as well as with the textdomain name when I submit the theme to themeforest.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with that.You can name the theme folder whatever you like and you can even name it full uppercase like TRUELOVE. As long as it's ok with wordpress ,themeforest won't care.

Comment: thanks much :) and any porblem with the textdomain name as TrueLove?

Comment: as far as know ,wordpress do not have such special rules for textdomain like"TrueLove".so you can use it.

Comment: And can I use this prefix 'TrueLove_' for that theme?

Comment: no,i will use truelove_ to replace wp_

Comment: Actually I would say for functions, classes etc. that must be attached with a unique prefix :)

Comment: as for that ,it seems that php is not case sensitive with function names,but preference is usually lower case. I think truelove_ is enough to avoid confliction.